# Is antonym the antonym of synonym?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

If an antonym is a word opposite in meaning to another,
and a synonym is a word exactly or nearly the same in meaning as another word.

Does this mean that **antonym** is the antonym of **synonym**?

Comment: What is the opposite of 'same' or 'similar'? What did a thesaurus say?

Comment: Yes.
Antonym is the anonym of Synonym and vice-versa; however, Synonym isn't the synonymof anotnym and vice-versa.

**Antonym** - Word that has meaning opposite to another: *Good - Evil*
**Synonym** - Word that has meaning similar to another: *Smart - Intelligent*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
The clues are in the Greek prefixes:

> anti- against, opposite, in answer to (antipodal, antiphony)

and

> syn-, sym- with, together, same (synonym, sympathy)

From: http://www.usu.edu/markdamen/Wordpower/handouts/gkaffix.pdf